# Mongoimport count numbers and import numbers are different

Tags: mongodb, import

I have a JSON File with 1730 documents. I run the import
with

```
D:\Apps\Mongo\Install\bin>mongoimport --db test --collection test --file MongoExport.json
```

It says imported 1730 documents but when I run a count on my test collection I only have 1000 documents.

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: No Errors in the Console

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I found a solution, though **I know** it's not the most elegant. Since each record in the dataset that I exported had its own unique `_id` value, I knew there was no chance of duplicate records, so I just ran the same json file through the importer a second time. The second pass look longer (since it was now having to determine whether to do an update or an insert for each record), but every record made it in! If it had missed some after the second pass, I would have done a third pass, but two passes was enough for 130,000+ records.

Note: Fiddling with the `writeConcern` did nothing for me.